# Como hago que no se resetee la pagina al enviar el formulario y que cuando la resetee la variable de php se formatee

Tags: php

Estoy creando una agenda tengo un formulario para llenar la agenda y un buscador para buscar el archivo con los datos de la persona pero, la pagina se resetea cuando envió el formulario y la variable que utilizo para buscar el archivo se queda cargada aunque resetee la pagina, y me sigue mostrando la búsqueda qué hice anteriormente

```
                    <form action="./index.php" method="post" class="form2">

                        <h2>Buscador de contactos</h2>


                        <div class="busca">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" id="busca" name="contacto" class="input">
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar Contactos" onclick="return contact()">

                        <textarea name="impresion" disabled>
                        <?php
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                            $busca = $_REQUEST["contacto"];
                            $ruta_archivo = "archivo/$busca.txt"; // Ruta al archivo
                            // Verificar si el archivo existe
                            if (file_exists($ruta_archivo)) {
                                $contenido = file_get_contents($ruta_archivo); // Obtener el contenido del archivo
                                // Imprimir el contenido en el textarea
                                echo htmlspecialchars($contenido); // Usar htmlspecialchars para escapar caracteres especiales
                            } else {
                                echo "Ingrese el nombre y apellido del contacto que desea buscar";
                            }
                            $busca = "";
                        } else {
                            // Si no se ha enviado ningún formulario POST, deja el textarea vacío
                            echo "Ingrese el nombre y apellido del contacto que desea buscar";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </textarea>

                    </form>
```

Intente hacer que el archivo se cerrara y que la variable este vacía cuando termine la función

Comment: SOY NUEVO EN PHP

Comment: El tipo de tu botón no debe ser _submit_ sino _button_ de manera que el formulario no se envíe al hacer click sobre él sino que se ejecute el script definido en el método 'onClick()'.